# How to use "case-when" in Ecto Queries in elixir?

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an SQL query like :
 `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN <table_name>.status = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM <table name>`.

I want to write the corresponding Ecto Query for the above. Something like:

```
from t in <table_name>, select: sum(...)
```

What is the analogy to "case-when" in the above case?

Comment: You probably can do it using fragments -> https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like the comment said, you can use `fragment/1`:

```
query = from t in <Model>, select: fragment("SUM(CASE WHEN status = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)", 2)
```

If you want to specify the table, this works for me:

```
query = from t in <Model>, select: fragment("SUM(CASE WHEN ? = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)", t.status, 2)
```

Comment: This works but just a small question...how can I associate a table name with status like "table_name".status in fragment?

Answer (score 8):

You can also leverage on macros to extend Ecto query language:

```
defmacro case_when(condition, do: then_expr, else: else_expr) do
  quote do
    fragment(
      "CASE WHEN ? THEN ? ELSE ? END",
      unquote(condition),
      unquote(then_expr),
      unquote(else_expr)
    )
  end
end
```

Then use it like this:

```
query = from t in <Model>,
  select: case_when t.status == 2
    do 1
    else 0
  end
```