# Ecto's fragment allowing SQL injection

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, sql-injection, ecto

When Ecto queries get more complex and require clauses like `CASE...WHEN...ELSE...END`, we tend to depend on Ecto's `fragment` to solve it.

e.g. `query = from t in <Model>, select: fragment("SUM(CASE WHEN status = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)", 2)`

In fact [the most popular Stack Overflow post about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022008/how-to-use-case-when-in-ecto-queries-in-elixir) suggests to create a macro like this:

```
defmacro case_when(condition, do: then_expr, else: else_expr) do
  quote do
    fragment(
      "CASE WHEN ? THEN ? ELSE ? END",
      unquote(condition),
      unquote(then_expr),
      unquote(else_expr)
    )
  end
end
```

so you can use it this way in your Ecto queries:

```
query = from t in <Model>,
  select: case_when t.status == 2
    do 1
    else 0
  end
```

at the same time, in another [post](https://elixirforum.com/t/ecto-not-allowing-string-interpolation-in-fragments/28459), I found this:

```
(Ecto.Query.CompileError) to prevent SQL injection attacks, fragment(...) does not allow strings to be interpolated as the first argument via the `^` operator, got: `"exists (\n        SELECT 1\n        FROM #{other_table} o\n        WHERE o.column_name = ?)"
```

Well, it seems Ecto's team figured out people are using `fragment` to solve complex queries, but they don't realize it can lead to SQL injection, so they don't allow string interpolation there as a way to protect developers.

Then comes another guy who says "don't worry, [use macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825904/create-ecto-query-with-dynamic-operators)."

I'm not an elixir expert, but that seems like a workaround to DO USE string interpolation, escaping the `fragment` protection.

Is there a way to use fragment and be sure the query was parameterized?

Comment: SQL injection is not something that jumps out of bushes and bites you. If you pass the data coming from the wild to the query, you’d better stick to `fragment/1` and maintain the defensive way of building queries. If it’s about the linked question, I showed how one might inject _either_ `:<` or _`:>`_.  It has not come from the wild, it’s clearly safe, and it’s absolutely safe to avoid [tag:ecto] checking _in this particular case_. That said, I do not think this question might be answered without seeing a real use case and I vote to close it as offtopic.

Comment: The question gravitates around what kind of protections ecto has in place when using it without fragment, which are lost when you use it?

Comment: I would assume there is something regarding prepared statements and how Ecto manage them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL injection, here, would result of string interpolation usage with an external data. Imagine `where: fragment("column = '#{value}'")` (instead of the correct `where: fragment("column = ?", value)`), if *value* comes from your `params` (usual name of the second argument of a Phoenix action which is the parameters extracted from the HTTP request), yes, this could result in a SQL injection.

But, the problem with prepared statement, is that you can't substitute a paremeter (the `?` in `fragment/1` string) by some dynamic SQL part (for example, a thing as simple as an operator) so, you don't really have the choice. Let's say you would like to write `fragment("column #{operator} ?", value)` because *operator* would be dynamic and depends on conditions, as long as *operator* didn't come from the user (harcoded somewhere in your code), it would be safe.

I don't know if you are familiar with PHP (PDO in the following examples), but this is exactly the same with `$bdd->query("... WHERE column = '{$_POST['value']}'")` (inject a value by string interpolation) in opposite to `$stmt = $bdd->prepare('... WHERE column = ?')` then `$stmt->execute([$_POST['value']]);` (a correct prepared statement). But, if we come back to my previous story of dynamic operator, as stated earlier, you can't dynamically bind some random SQL fragment, the DBMS would interpret `"WHERE column ? ?"` with `>` as operator and `'foo'` as value like (for the idea) `WHERE column '>' 'foo'` which is not syntactically correct. So, the easiest way to turn this operator dynamic is to write `"WHERE column {$operator} ?"` (inject it, but only it, by string interpolation or concatenation). If this variable `$operator` is defined by your own code (eg: `$operator = some_condition ? '>' : '=';`), it's fine but, in the opposite, if it involves some superglobal variable which comes from the client like `$_POST` or `$_GET`, this creates a security hole (SQL injection).

TL;DR

> Then comes another guy who says "don't worry, [use macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825904/create-ecto-query-with-dynamic-operators)."

The answer of Aleksei Matiushkin, in the mentionned post, is just a workaround to the disabled/forbidden string interpolation by `fragment/1` to dynamically inject a **known** operator. If you reuse this trick (and can't really do otherwise), as long as you don't blindly "inject" any random value coming from the user, you'll be fine.

UPDATE:

It seems, after all, that `fragment/1` (which I didn't inspect the source) doesn't imply a prepared statement (the `?` are not placeholder of a true prepared statement). I tried some simple and stupid enough query like the following:

```
from(
  Customer,
  where: fragment("lastname ? ?", "LIKE", "%")
)
|> Repo.all()
```

At least with PostgreSQL/postgrex, the generated query in console appears to be in fact:

SELECT ... FROM "customers" AS c0 WHERE (lastname 'LIKE' '%') []

Note the `[]` (empty list) at the end for the parameters (and absence of `$1` in the query) so it seems to act like the emulation of prepared statement in PHP/PDO meaning Ecto (or postgrex?) realizes proper escaping and injection of values directly in the query but, still, as said above `LIKE` became a string (see the `'` surrounding it), not an operator so the query fails with a syntax error.